# html+css, put a button next to ul without table

Tags: html, css, css-float

[image: the result]

Here is what I want to achieve ^

Here's how it works now: http://jsfiddle.net/yfxPm/1/

The problem is that if I put float:left than the rest of the content will go inside

```
    <div class='field'>
    <ul class='display'>
    <li>apple</li>
    </ul>
    <button class='btn'>...</button>
    <div>
<button>this button will go inside .field div </button>
```

(clear:both on .field doesn't help)
The css:

```
.field
{ 
    width: 200px;
    margin: 1em;
}
.display
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: solid 1px gray;
    background: white;
    float: left;    
}
```

One solution would be to put a `<br style="clear:both" />` before the end of the .field div but this will add some additional padding

Comment: Are you sure you should be using an `ul` element here? Looks like you want a `select`.

Comment: can you show what it is currently doing, like what it looks like?

Comment: @bash sure, here you go http://jsfiddle.net/yfxPm/1/

Comment: @omu for correctly using the clear property, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, Ma, no floats!

**HTML**

```
    <div>
    <ul>
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Papaya</li>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit">&hellip;</button>    
</div>
<button>should be below</button>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
div { display:block; }
ul { display:inline-block; }
button { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; }
```

Answer (score 3):

here is how to use clear:both properly

HTML:

```
    <div class="field">
       <ul class="display">
            <li>apple</li>
            <li>apple</li>
            <li>apple</li>
            <li>apple</li>
       </ul>
       <button class='btn'>...</button>
       <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
<button>should be below</button>
```

CSS:

```
.field
{ 
    width: 200px;
    margin: 1em;
}
.display
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: solid 1px gray;
    background: white;
    float: left;    
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Using an empty div with class clear, will clear the float and not add any padding. Also it will render the same way on different browsers

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: hidden` might be more suitable here.

```
<div class="field">
   <button class='btn'>...</button>
   <ul class="display">
        <li>apple</li>
        <li>apple</li>
        <li>apple</li>
        <li>apple</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<button>should be below</button>
```

```
.field {
    margin: 1em;
    overflow: hidden; /*Clear the floated children */
}
.display
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: solid 1px gray;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden; /*Leave a gap on the right for the button*/    
}
.btn {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking something like

```
<div class='field' style="float:left">
    <ul class='display'>
        <li>apple</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="float:left">
    <button class='btn'>...</button>
<div>
```

Should work

Comment: Sorry, I missed the 2nd button in your question. I blame lack of coffee